# Which cloud to use for RabbitMQ?

Tags: azure, rabbitmq, saas, bitnami

We are looking for a cloud based solution for messaging queue. We have chosen RabbitMQ and we already have few app that are using this. RabbitMQ is hosted locally. For testing purposes it was ok, but right now when business is growing and we are looking into centralised RabbitMQ with HA we are looking into cloud solution.

My question is: which service would you recommend for RabbitMQ,

the options that we've found are:

cloudamqp.com/

https://addons.heroku.com/rabbitmq-bigwig

https://bitnami.com and use Azure

or

host it in Azure and manage by ourself - but we would like to avoid this as much as possible - not enough human resources to look after that.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 8):

my suggestion is http://cloudamqp.com - i use them for just about of all my RabbitMQ hosting needs, for production web apps.

it's a fully managed RabbitMQ hosting service. you don't have to worry about much, and you can get as large / scalable as you need. From very small and cheap, to enterprise level hosting with clustering, etc.

Comment: have you tried any other? we need also to justify why we are using that one, why not others. for management we need to prepare some comparison.

Comment: i've been using cloudamqp for several years now, and i run my own rmq server for one client. don't have much comparison other than that... but you said it best, yourself: "manage by ourself - but we would like to avoid this as much as possible - not enough human resources to look after that."

Comment: I'm quite happy with CloudAMQP so far, it has help up pretty well during load testing and is quite easy to use.  Has a good Diagnostics page that reports any issues with your service, clients, etc, and also has a useful Security page that lets you lock down access by IP address.  Ideal when the cost of building RabbitMQ expertise would be much higher than cost of the service.  My experience is that running a RabbitMQ cluster is not as easy as it looks.